# Firebase in Android Studio Assistant, exception error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-assistant

I am trying to build an app with android studio 3.5 , I want to use Firebase, but whenever I open up the Firebase assistant window an IDE exception error pops up. I've tried disabling and re-enabling the firebase plugins, I've even reinstalled Android Studio. Please help me.

**Here's the error:**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:75)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.getDependencyState(DependencyStateManager.java:59)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.init(DependencyStateManager.java:108)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.StatefulButton.<init>(StatefulButton.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialStep.<init>(TutorialStep.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.redraw(TutorialCard.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.<init>(TutorialCard.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.FeaturesPanel.<init>(FeaturesPanel.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel.createFeaturesPanel(AssistSidePanel.kt:113)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel.access$createFeaturesPanel(AssistSidePanel.kt:35)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel$AssistantLoadingCallback.completed(AssistSidePanel.kt:124)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel$AssistantLoadingCallback.completed(AssistSidePanel.kt:118)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistantGetBundleTask.onSuccess(AssistantGetBundleTask.kt:23)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.finishTask(CoreProgressManager.java:502)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.lambda$run$0(CoreProgressManager.java:421)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:706)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO! take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html as it might help you understand the problem! `Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist.`

Comment: @pep1 it sounds like OP has this problem when starting a plugin in Android Studio, in which case their own code is unlikely to be involved, and thus no way for them to fix it by changing that code.

Comment: Hey Stephan, if this happens before you even write any code, it is unlikely that anyone here can help, and more likely a bug in the Firebase Assistant. Please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the Firebase team.

Comment: I recommend also not using the Firebase Assistant, as it's known to have problems.   There is documentation for getting started without the assistant, and I highly recommend doing things that way.